# Webaii Opening/running Internet Explorer as different user

Tags: c#, telerik, automation, webaii

Is it possible to open/running IE as different users using Webaii?

I know manually you can hold down shift and right click windows explorer in 'All Programs' from the Windows Start menu and select 'Run as different user'. But is it possible to open an IE browser using Webaii and entering different user account details (username and password)?

The reason I ask is because I want to check that when logging onto a SilverLight web site with users with different permissions that certain things are hidden/visible.

If is not possible I will have to open the IE browser manually. Is there a way to make my code to shift focus to the manually opened browser?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Andy, I work for Telerik in the Test Studio and Webaii technical support department. I will endeavor to help you out.

I am sorry to report I have mostly bad news for you. 1) No it is not possible to make Webaii launch the browser under different credentials. 2) No it is not possible to make Webaii connect to an already opened browser.

As an alternative I suggest running the program which is executing your Webaii test under different credentials. Webaii will launch the browser under whatever credentials the current process is executing under. Thus you may be logged into your machine as "Andy" then run Visual Studio as "Jane", run your Webaii test within Visual Studio and Webaii will launch the browser as "Jane".

I hope that helps.

Cody